# App crashing on fireDate Swift iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

I register the notification using the following line:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound|UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
```

And this function sets the notifications:

```
func setNotification(verseRecord:NSManagedObject) {
        var verseDate :String=verseRecord.valueForKeyPath("date")as String
        var timeString : String =  "7:00am";
        var datetimeString : String =  verseDate + " " + timeString
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma"
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone();
        var date = formatter.dateFromString(datetimeString)
        let lang = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("language");
        var record:String=verseRecord.valueForKeyPath(lang!) as String

        var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
        localNotification.alertBody=record
        println(date!);
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone();
        localNotification.fireDate=date! IApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

The app crashes on this line only on the iPhone 6 and iPad Air 2:

```
localNotification.fireDate=date!
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting, your question is hard to read.

Comment: Done formatting, Please check...

Comment: Probably the date formatter fail to get a proper date retuning an optional that you are forcing to unwrap